# Public Autocomplete on Drupal User Registration

Tags: drupal, registration, autocomplete

I've been testing the Public Autocomplete extension with the hope of using it to prevent duplicate contacts being created if I expose the current employer field in forms. I've got it working for anonymous users on an event registration page but, using the same profile, it doesn't seem to work on the Drupal User Registration form.

Is this be design, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be an ACL or Drupal Permission. I can't get it to work for authenticated users but it does work for Admins. I'm not sure what the fix is.